# how can i make function with list and dictionary become summary?

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, transactions

i have the data sample:

```
bought = ['Banana','Banana','Pineapple','Pineapple']
price_of = {'Apple': 6, 'Avocado': 5, 'Banana': 3, 'Blackberries': 10, 'Blueberries':12, 'Cherries': 7, 'Pineapple': 7}
def summary(bought, price_of):
    for bought,n in price_of:
       multi = bought[keys] * price_of['keys']
       print(fruit_price[values],':', values)
       if total >= 10:
          print('discount', total * 5/10)
```

i still confuse to solve it and i want to make discount 5 if  minimum total bought is 10
i want to output like that:

```
2 Banana : 6
2 pineapple : 14
total : 20
discount price : #showing discount price
```

Comment: Your code does not appear to even *attempt* to handle the discount price.

Comment: To start sanitizing this code fragment: 1. `bought` should not be a loop variable and a function input at the same time, that is confusing at least. 2. `keys` and `values` are not defined anywhere. 3. `'keys'` is not a key in `price_of`. 4. Once we are in the for loop, `bought` is a string and probably should not be indexed/can not be indexed with another string. 5. `total` ist not defined.

Comment: can u guide me to solve it step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bought = ['Banana','Banana','Pineapple','Pineapple']
price_of = {'Apple': 6, 'Avocado': 5, 'Banana': 3, 'Blackberries': 10, 'Blueberries':12, 'Cherries': 7, 'Pineapple': 7}

def get_summary(items):
    result = {}
    for item in items:
        if not item in result:
            result[item] = {
                'count': 0,
                'price': 0
            }

        result[item]['price'] += price_of[item]
        result[item]['count'] += 1
    return result


def print_summary(items):
    total = 0
    for key in items:
        total += items[key]['price']
        print('{} {} {}'.format(items[key]['count'], key, items[key]['price']))
    print('Total: {}'.format(total))
    if total >= 10:
        print('Discount: {}'.format(total * 0.5))


print_summary(get_summary(bought))

# 2 Banana 6
# 2 Pineapple 14
# Total: 20
# Discount: 10.0
```